# OpenCV - 3.0 Camera calibration gives an error

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I was previously doing camera calibration using OpenCV-2.4.10. Now I have installed OpenCV-3.0.0 and run the same code. [This](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html) is the link of the code.

With the previous version it was working fine, but in `OpenCV-3.0.0` it is giving an error.

> TypeError: Required argument 'cameraMatrix' (pos 4) not found

can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Any if I add cameraMatrix (Pos4) ,and distcoeff(Pos5), it gives an error :

> TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Answer (score 3):

I got exactly the same error

```
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

But it turned out I was passing the shape of the image as ImageSize before transforming to grayscale, so a tuple of 3 values instead of 2, OpenCV has really confusing errors sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, you have to pass camera width and height, in my case I used this code line:

```
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(_3d_points, 
                                                   _2d_points, 
                                                   (im.shape[1], im.shape[0]), 
                                                   None,
                                                   None)
```

Here `im.shape[1]` is the width and `im.shape[0]` is the height, basically returning the size of the image, also make sure the images are converted to grayscale.

In my case after converting the images to grayscale and adding the above line of code helped me get the o/p.

Answer (score 1):

This stumped me too, but now you need to pass `None` for each.

```
retval, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objectPoints,imagePoints, imageSize, None, None)
```

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html#calibration

Comment: giving None doesn't solve the problem, still the same issue

Comment: What is the error you get, exactly? If you pass two `None`'s then you should get a different error to the previous one.

Comment: i got exactly the same error 

    TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
But it turned out I was passing the shape of the image as ImageSize before transforming to grayscale, so a tuple of 3 values instead of 2, OpenCV has really confusing errors sometimes.

Comment: @Mehdi Thank you so much.  This solved my problem - the poor documentation of some OpenCV functions alone make my hairs curl, but the cryptic error messages really set me off.

Comment: @rayryeng In opencv if you're asked for image size it's always 2D regardless of depth and it's (width, height) eg (640,480) unlike the shape in Numpy which is (height, width, channels). This is because the underlying c++ usually requires a cv::size object. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d50/classcv_1_1Size__.html note the constructor is (w, h) order

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(
    objpoints, imgpoints, frame.shape[::-1][1:3], None, None
)
```

frame.shape is the img size you used to calibrate